# Filter pivot table in laravel using IN in the input array

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I am trying to filter data from the pivot table. My pivot table is something like this:

```
Treatment_products:
treatment_product_id   treatment_id   product_id   qty
65                     29             29           22
66                     29             26           12
67                     22             34           26
```

I am using this mysql query which is giving the perfect output what i want.

```
SELECT * FROM treatments_products 

WHERE (product_id,qty) IN ((29,2334),(29,23343),(26,0)) AND treatment_id = 29
```

I want to do the same in the laravel. I found a link on the stackoverflow in which someone mentioned to use wherepivot I tried to do that but not able to found the results.

```
$treatments = Treatment::with(array('products'=>function($query) use ($whereIn){
            $query->wherePivot('product_id,qty','IN',$whereIn);
        }))->get();
```

Can someone please let me know that what I am doing wrong or how can i do that in laravel?

Thanks.